# ¿Explicación llenado Matrices en JAVA?

Tags: java, array, matrices, array-bidimensional

Lo que quiero es llenar Matrices con valores que vaya digitando el usuario según la posición de la matriz.

Por defecto asigne 2 valores predeterminados en la posición `(0,0)` y `(0,1)` Correspondientes a `Id`,`Nombre`.
Sin embargo quiero que llegado a la columna del `id`, pregunte por el `id`, y llegado a la columna del nombre, pregunte por el nombre. Para dar resultado una tabla estilo así:

| id | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pepito |
| 2 | herbie |

Lo que se sucede es que entra dos veces a la misma posición `(i,j)`. la verdad no entiendo muy bien el tema de Matrices.

```java
 public class matriz2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String id,nombre;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite el número de personas a digitar");
        int num = entrada.nextInt();
        num = num+1;
        String matriz2 [][] = new String[num][2];
        for (int i=0;i<matriz2.length;i++){
            for (int j =0;j<matriz2[i].length;j++){
                if (matriz2[i][j] == matriz2[0][0] ){
                    matriz2[i][j] = "Id";
                }
                else if (matriz2[i][j] == matriz2[0][1] ){
                    matriz2[i][j] = "Nombre";
                }
                else{
                System.out.println("Digite el id: en la posición matriz ["+i+"] ["+j+"]");
                id = entrada.next();
                matriz2[i][j]= id;
                System.out.println("Digite el Nombre: ");
                nombre = entrada.next();
                matriz2[i][j]= nombre;
     
                }
            }
            
        }
        entrada.close();
        ver_matriz(matriz2);
    }
   //metodo para mostrar matriz.
    public  static void ver_matriz(String matriz[][]){
        for (int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int j =0;j<matriz[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print (matriz[i][j]+ "|");
                }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pongo una posible forma de hacerlo formateando la salida con espacios para que quede el texto contenido en la matriz alineado por filas y columnas y el encabezado coloreado de azul

¡ ojo !, porque el método:

```
String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, s));
```

Funciona a partir de java 8.0

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //viriables tipo string para id y nombre
    String id,nombre;
    //instanciamos la clase scanner
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    //pedimos el número de filas del array que equivaldrá al número de personas
    System.out.println("Digite el número de personas a digitar");
    //recogemos el número en la variable num y le sumamos 1 por la fila de los encabezados
    int num = entrada.nextInt() + 1;
    //limpiamos el buffer de la entrada después de un valor numérico
    entrada.nextLine();
    //esto resulta reticente, se elimina, sería repetir que el valor introducido por teclado y almacenado en la variable num es igual al valor que almacenaremos en la variable num
    //num = num;
    //declaramos la matriz bidimensional de string con el límite de filas pedido por consola y dos columnas
    String[][] matriz2 = new String[num][2];
    //en la posición 0,0 y 0,1 del array, almacenamos los encabezados id y nombre
    matriz2[0][0] = "Id";
    matriz2[0][1] = "Nombre";
    //declaramos un bucle for que recorrerá las filas
    for (int i = 1; i < matriz2.length; i++){
        //declaramos un bucle for que recorrerá las columnas
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz2[0].length; j++){
            //si la variable del bucle es igual a 0 (primera iteración)
            if (j == 0){
                //pedimos el id
                System.out.println("Digite el id: en la posición matriz [" + i + "] [" + j + "]");
                //recogemos el id en la variable string id
                matriz2[i][j]= entrada.nextLine();
            }
            //si la variable j es igual 1 (segunda iteración)
            if (j == 1){
                //pedimos el nombre
                System.out.println("Digite el Nombre: en la misma posición matriz [" + i + "] [" + j + "]");
                //almacenamos el nombre en la viable string nombre
                nombre = entrada.nextLine();
                //almacenamos el valor de la variable nombre en la posicion de la matriz
                matriz2[i][j]= nombre;
            }
        }
    }
    //cerramos la clase escaner
    entrada.close();

    //llamamos al método ver matriz y enviamos la matriz por parámetro
    ver_matriz(matriz2);
}
//metodo para mostrar matriz.
public static void ver_matriz(String[][] matriz) {
    //declaramos un string con un espacio
    String espa = " ";
    //dibujamos una línea para separar la parte anterior dl ejercicio
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    //especificamos lo que veremos a continuación
    System.out.println("Imprimimos los Datos de la Lista de Personas: ");
    //bucle que recorre las filas
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
        //bucle que recorre las columnas
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            //declaramos un variable string que recoge el string id de la matriz principal
            String idS = matriz[i][0].toString();
            //declaramos una variable de un valor entero que recoge el número de caracteres del string de la matriz principal
            int id = idS.length();
            //si estamos en la primera fila de los encabezados
            if (i == 0){
                //si estamos en el primer valor de las columnas
                if (j == 0){
                    //por el método join de la clase string, usamos el método nCopies de Collections para copiar 3 veces el string espa creado anteriormente y ahora imprimimos en azul el encabezado
                    System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(3, espa)) +
                    "\033[31m" + matriz[i][j]);
                }
                else if (j == 1){
                    //En función del valor de id con el número de caracteres que trae
                    switch (id){
                        //si es uno
                        case 1:
                            //por el método join de la clase string, usamos el método nCopies de Collections para copiar 7 veces el string espa creado anteriormente y ahora imprimimos el valor del array
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(7, espa)) +
                            "\033[31m" + matriz[i][j]);
                            //salimons del switch
                            break;
                        //si es dos
                        case 2:
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(6, espa)) +
                            "\033[31m" + matriz[i][j]);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(5, espa)) +
                            "\033[31m" + matriz[i][j]);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(4, espa)) +
                            "\033[31m" + matriz[i][j]);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(3, espa)) +
                            "\033[31m" + matriz[i][j]);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //si el valor de i no es cero
            else {
                //si j es cero
                if (j == 0){
                    System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(3, espa)) +
                    matriz[i][j]);
                }
                //si j es 1
                if (j == 1){
                    //según el valor de la variable id con el número de caracteres
                    switch (id){
                        //si es uno
                        case 1:
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(7, espa)) +
                            matriz[i][j]);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(6, espa)) +
                            matriz[i][j]);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(5, espa)) +
                            matriz[i][j]);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(4, espa)) +
                            matriz[i][j]);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(3, espa)) +
                            matriz[i][j]);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //creamos una línea en blanco
        System.out.println("");
    }
    //creamos una línea para separar código
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
}
```